# Illegal string offset 'class' + PHP 5.4.45 + Yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii

I have app with YII 1.1 working with PHP 5.3.29 with CPANEL + EASY PHP. It's working.

I need to updgrade into PHP 5.4.45, but when we do. The application stopped working and start giving the error like the print screen.

[print sreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG0wz.png)

I already Setup the same version of YII + PHP in pc and it's working.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The warning means, your $module is a string and you are trying to use it as array. You need to make sure the type of your $module type is array.

You can use [is_array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp) to check before you go into your block.

Comment: The issue was related with configuration file for YII. In the section all itens should be a array and one of them were a string.  I removed and it's working.